# Combining overviews for large multiband raster image

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, image-pyramids, virtual-raster

I have several large rasters, complete with overviews. I have combined these as separate bands of a multiband virtual raster. However, QGIS performs very slow viewing this `vrt`. Is there a fast way to produce an overview for this `vrt`?

Comment: You can create a new image from vrt with bigger pixel size by using gdal_translate and -size parameter. Then you can edit the vrt file and define this new image to be used as overview https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html. Or then just open that new image with QGIS as well and set scale based visibility for the coarse image and for the vrt layer. VRT should be fast at big scales when not so many image files needs to be opened for filling the map view.

Answer (score 1):

The `.ovr` overview is a multipage TIFF, consisting of successively coarser images. For the overview of a multiband image (as produced by `gdaladdo`) each of those pages is itself a multiband image.

In principle it should be possible to:

1. Split the pages, from each band's overview, into separate files (almost by streaming i.e. without decompressing the image data),
2. Collate those pages by resolution (e.g. build a multiband vrt for each zoom factor)
3. Re-encode the image data, as a multiband TIFF image for each zoom factor. (Only at this step the image data may need to be decompressed and recompressed, to facilitate the reorganisation.)
4. Gather the multiband series together as pages of a single file.

A complication is that Libtiff utilities don't have great support for GDAL extensions (such as the nodata value tag); ImageMagick utilities (e.g. `convert`) have a tendency to always (prematurely) decompress the data into an image in memory.

As for GDAL utilities: `gdaladdo` accepts a `COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS` option, but still seems inexplicably slow. May be able to copy a page by referring to it as `GTIFF_DIR:<page$>:<filename>`?